# Nivo Slider - Stop animation when only one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, nivo-slider

I am using the jQuery plugin for Nivo Slider and need to find a way to stop it from transitioning when only one image exists.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the option:

```
manualAdvance: true
```

Will that help? [This](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/) is the documentation for the latest NivoSlider update.

If this wont help, can you post the code you are using to enable the slider?

This will be the full code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        slices: 1, // For slice animations
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        manualAdvance: true, // Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity: 0.8, // Universal caption opacity
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting manual advance to true also effect the slider when there are multiple photos.  I guess I could check the number of items and then set the slider accordingly.  I will have to look into that and report back, thanks for pointing out that option!

Comment: I totally agree with you about checking "manually" the number of items... Write some code and post it and I will try to help you if I can....

Comment: Well it turns out nivo slider isn't going to work for me anyway, I need something that can handle different size images and scale them without distortion.

Comment: That is true, I had the exact same problem about handle different size images.... Check [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/), may that helps you..... It is similar to facebook I think.

Comment: I don't want the images to pop up is the thing, I need for the user to be able to see the rest of the page and navigate around while the slider is going.  The slider is to display images on the homepage while the user looks around.  Most of the lightbox libraries I have found popup the image and center it on the screen while dimming the rest of the page.

Comment: @Nath5 please select this or any other answer as the "selected answer" (green check).

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better way to do it but it works for me:

```
if($('#slider img').length == 1) {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({});
    $('.nivo-controlNav').css('display', 'none');
    $('.nivo-directionNav').css('display', 'none');
    $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').stop = true;
} else {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'slideInLeft'
    });
}
```

PS. It's important to check the number of images before initializing Nivoslider because it seems to duplicate image tags...

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers quite worked for me, because I still wanted a single image to display with a caption. I ended up using slightly different options to initialise the nivoSlider depending on the number of images (my images were in a containing div with the id 'hero-images'):

```
            var numImages = $('#hero-images img').length;

            if (numImages === 0) {
                //No images - hide the block
                $('#hero-images').hide();
            } else if (numImages === 1) {
                // 1 image - disable controls and set to manual advance to prevent animation
                $('#hero-images').nivoSlider({
                    directionNav: false,
                    manualAdvance: true,
                    controlNav: false
                });
            } else {
                // Multiple images, set up as normal
                $('#hero-images').nivoSlider({
                    effect: 'fade',
                    directionNav: false
                });
            }
```